# How to use getState with redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have an action creator called searchResult() that grabs data from Firebase and then filters it against a piece of state called 'search' from another reducer called SearchReducer (created by the action creator searchChanged()).  Here's how the code looks:

```
 export const searchResult = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
       return (dispatch, getState) => {

    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/entries`)
       .orderByChild('uid')
         .on('value', snapshot => {
          const myObj = snapshot.val();
          const { search } = getState().searching;

          const list = _.pickBy(myObj, (((value) => 
             value.make.indexOf(search) !== -1 || 
             value.model.indexOf(search) !== -1) && ((value) => 
             value.sold === false)));


             dispatch({ type: SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS, payload: list });
     });
    };
   };
```

The code runs, but nothing gets filtered.  With the redux debugger, I can see that 'search' changes.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's other pieces of my code:

The Action Creator searchChanged():

```
 export const searchChanged = (text) => {
   return {
      type: SEARCH_CHANGED,
      payload: text
     };
   };
```

The Reducer SearchReducer:

```
 import {
    SEARCH_CHANGED,
 } from '../actions/types';

 const INITIAL_STATE = {
   search: '',
 };

 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
     case SEARCH_CHANGED:
       return { ...state, search: action.payload };
   default:
       return state;
   }
  };
```

searchResult()'s Reducer called EntryReducer:

```
import {
  SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS,
  ENTRY_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  SOLD_RESULT_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = [];


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ENTRY_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    case SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    case SOLD_RESULT_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here's the combineReducers() function:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';
import EntryFormReducer from './EntryFormReducer';
import EntryReducer from './EntryReducer';
import SearchReducer from './SearchReducer';
import PasswordReducer from './PasswordReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  entryForm: EntryFormReducer,
  employees: EntryReducer,
  searching: SearchReducer,
  pw: PasswordReducer
});
```

And here's where searchChanged() is called followed by searchResult():

```
class Search extends Component {

   //onSearchChange() is just the onChangeText binding for the text input.
   onSearchChange(text) {
     this.props.searchChanged(text);
     searchResult();
 }
```

========================= Newly Edited Part ===============================

Now I'm using mapDispatchToProps inside my Search component. But, I'm still either getting errors, or just nothing happens when I type into the search input. The entire component looks like this (it returns an error that searchResult isn't a function. I'm getting my direction from https://learn.co/lessons/map-dispatch-to-props-readme):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import { searchChanged, searchResult } from '../actions';
import Card from './common/Card';
import CardSection from './common/CardSection';
import Input from './common/Input';


class Search extends Component {

  onSearchChange(text) {
    this.props.searchChanged(text);
    this.store.props.dispatch(searchResult());
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>

       <Input
         placeholder="Search"
         onChangeText={this.onSearchChange.bind(this)}
         value={this.props.search}
         returnKeyType={'search'}
       />

       </View>
   );
  }
 }


 const mapStateToProps = state => {

   return {
     search: state.searching.search
    };
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    searchResult: searchResult
  }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchChanged }, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

Only using:

```
 onSearchChange(text) {
this.props.searchChanged(text);
dispatch(searchResult());
}
```

returns an error that dispatch is a an undeclared variable.   How do I format this component correctly so that it understands mapDispatchToState correctly?

Comment: Did you try to modify your action in your class from searchResult() to this.props.searchResult()?

Comment: You have to call `dispatch(searchResult())`

Comment: @DennisFrea Yeah, I tried that as well...same result.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Eric Guan   Where would I call dispatch (searchResult())? I tried to call it inside of searchChanged(), but I might have the syntax wrong.  What would that look like specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly where you call `searchResult()`, inside `onSearchChange`. Instead of calling `searchResult()`, call `dispatch(searchResult())`  You'll need to import the redux store to access the dispatch function. OR if you're using react-redux, use mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: Hey @EricGuan, Thank you so much for helping me out here! I sooo appreciate it.  I've been trying a couple of things with mapDispatchToProps, and none are working. (see edited code above)  I'm not trying to be 'spoon fed' here, but do you see anywhere in the Search component where I've gone astray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your app level code.

import searchResult from '../actions/list-actions';

```
onSearchChange(text) {
    this.props.searchResult(text);

  }


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        yourListName: state.yourListName,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        searchResult: (data) => dispatch(searchResult(data)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search)
```

Then in actions...

```
export const SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS = list => ({
    type: 'SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS',
    payload: list,
});

   export const searchResult = (data) => dispatch {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
       return (dispatch, getState) => {

    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/entries`)
       .orderByChild('uid')
         .on('value', snapshot => {
          const myObj = snapshot.val();
          const { search } = getState().searching;

          const list = _.pickBy(myObj, (((value) => 
             value.make.indexOf(search) !== -1 || 
             value.model.indexOf(search) !== -1) && ((value) => 
             value.sold === false)));
        //!!!Do you filtering HERE based on the data (or search value) passed in 
            through the app level. 
        //Then dispatch the save of the newly edited list to your redux store.
        //Or based on your use case take just the article that matched, and store 
          it to a searched category in the store.  
             dispatch(SEARCH_RESULT_SUCCESS(list));
     });
    };
   };

};
```

Comment: Thanks so much @GavinThomas!  I'm trying to configure my code and specific use case to your code, but have no idea how to format the onSearchChange() function in my code above.  Can I see all the parts of your component's code that pertain to mapDispatchToProps or mapStateToProps?  Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Does this make more sense? I can't write all of it for you without being apart of the project

Comment: Wow! Thanks for taking your time on Christmas Eve!  I think this makes sense...when I first started trying to build a search filter, I wasn't aware of mapDispatchToProps.  So, in my ignorance, I thought I'd just create a piece of state called 'search' that was generated by whatever was typed into the search filter input (searchChanged()).  Then just grab that piece of state with getState and filter away in my action searchResult().  But because every time the user types into the search filter text input, searchResult() needs to be called. Do I even need getState/searchChanged()?

Comment: With your code, it appears that you just pass (text) into searchResult() as an argument, and then filter with at argument inside of searchResult().  I'm going to try that and get back...Merry Christmas and thank you so so much!

Comment: //You can do it multiple ways. It's open for discussion. I'm still unsure what your data set is. However lets say this is 1000's of articles and you are searching by keyword? databaseRef.child("Articles").queryOrdered(byChild: "body").queryEqual(toValue: text)

I would grab the entire, completed "text" word that the user inputs to search firebase before pulling that data down. 
When Firebase runs the search on their servers (better for you) then just save and display what they return to redux store.

Comment: //Second use case, your data set isn't large AND what you're currently doing. Lets say you want to do like a fuzzy search, where articles appear as the user keeps typing words. (which is how your current code is setup because you are passing "text" through your search. ) You pull all articles from firebase EVERY TIME the user adds or removes letters. This can be expensive because you are essentially making calls to firebase "text".length which is a lot.

Comment: //The adjustment I would make to this while you are still learning is to query firebase based on an initial category like all "articles" then, store them into your redux store as articles. Then at your app level run your filtering with the "text" that the user is inputting from articles at the app level. This save database queries, and would not be ideal without pagination for large data sets. All this being said the first option would be most efficient.

Comment: Good point, I guess I don't really want to continually be querying firebase.  I want to query it once, then filter it in a different action ( I don't forsee there being 1,000's of items in the database).  I think I'm going to have to hunker down and really just go through every tutorial Dan Abramov has out there and really become acquainted with Redux, React-Redux, and Redux-Thunk.  Otherwise, you're going to be explaining things for weeks.  Thanks for everything you've done!  It has really helped, especially the point about constantly querying firebase. And Merry Christmas!

Comment: lol no problem, I really try to push people to use redux, it's awesome! Just think of the store as virtual compartments that can hold data. And their names are what you use in the reducers! Your actions should mainly be populating these compartments from outside sources (also filtering I suppose).  Heres a link for reference. This is a project of mine. Look through the actions if you'd like and see how they correlate into the app level code. https://github.com/arn1313/kritter-frontend/tree/master/src . keep on learning!

Comment: Thanks so much! I refactored the code to not need to call mapDispatchToProps. But it is still missing something very small. I haven’t committed anything to github yet. Do you have a Facebook or twitter that I can show you what I did? I am really loving the possibilities of React, and it might be good to connect with some React developers.

Comment: Yea, github is incredibly important and you should really learn that asap! It's like the best thing ever for code sharing. https://twitter.com/gthomas_me